# Probability of two points being part of two segments of different size

Tags: probability

This may be an easy question but my probability skills are a bit rusty since I haven't used them for while.

Say that we have a line with ten consecutive points. We are to choose two segments out of this line, one with length 3 and one with length 4. I am trying to calculate the probability of a point being part of both segments. I thought that I would make use of indicator random variables but I have trouble setting up the probability for a point being in one sequence.

If we for example take the sequence with consecutive points its starting point can be placed in 8 different positions. Now the probability of each point being in this sequence is different. For example the first point has probability $1/8$, whereas the second point has probability $2/8$ and so forth. Any advise on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  You might as well consider the line to be $[0,9]$  How many choices are there for the first point of the segment of length $3$?    How many choices are there for the first point of the segment of length $4$?  Multiply those and you have the size of the sample space.  Now it is easier to hand count the number of ways to pick two segments that don't overlap.

Answer (score 2):

I am inferring from the question that the points are one unit apart and that the segments start from one point.   Label the points 0 to 9.   Let the two segments be $S_3$ and $S_4$.

The segment of length 3, $S_3$, will be a set of *four* points and can start from point 0 to point 6.

The segment of length 4, $S_4$, will be a set of *five* points that may start from point 0 to point 5.

Then the probability of point $n$ being in a segment is:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(n\in S_3)
 & = \begin{cases} \frac{n+1}{7} &:  n\in\{0,1,2,3\}
 \\ \frac 4 7 &: n\in\{4,5\}
 \\ \frac{10-n}{7} &: n\in\{6,7,8,9\}
 \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(n\in S_4)
 & = \begin{cases} \Box &:  n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}
 \\ \Box &: n\in\{5,6,7,8,9\}
 \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(n\in (S_3\cap S_4))
 & = \mathsf P(n\in S_3)\mathsf P(n\in S_4)
\\[1ex]
 & = \begin{cases}\Box &: n\in\{0,1,2,3\}
 \\ \Box &: n\in\{4,5\}
 \\ \Box &: n\in\{6,7,8,9\}
 \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

Comment: Yes thank you. I did something similar. Is possible to model the endpoints in a more general way? @Graham Kemp